# makeindex and fourier's mathbb

Tags: indexing, fourier

In the example document below the second index entry produces the warning

```
!! Input index error (file = j.idx, line = 2):
   -- Extra `@' at position 11 of first argument.
```

on running `makeglossaries` corresponding to

```
\indexentry{A@\( \mathbb A \)}{1}
\indexentry{R@\( \math@bb  R \)}{1}
\indexentry{B@\( B \)}{1}
```

in the `.idx` file.  As a result the second entry is rejected and does not appear in the `.ind` file or index.

As the first entry shows, a work around is to move the `\index` command outside of `\emph`.  But swapping the `fourier` package for `amssymb` demonstrates that it is not necessary in general.

Is there a way to modify the behaviour of the `fourier` package so such index entries work inside `\emph`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fourier}
%\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

The \index{A@\( \mathbb A \)}%
\emph{\index{R@\( \mathbb R \)}%
\index{B@\( B \)}real numbers \( \mathbb R \)}.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reasons, `fourier.sty` doesn't do

```
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbb}{Ufutm}
```

but

```
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\math@bb}{Ufutm}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\mathbb\math@bb
  [...<code omitted>...]
}
```

so the first level expansion of `\mathbb` becomes `\protect\math@bb` and the latter macro name gets written in the `.idx` file.

Workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fourier}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\protected\def\mathbb{\math@bb}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

The \index{A@\( \mathbb{A} \)}%
\emph{\index{R@\( \mathbb{R} \)}%
\index{B@\( B \)}real numbers \( \mathbb{R} \)}.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

This is the `.idx` file

```
\indexentry{A@\( \mathbb{A} \)}{1}
\indexentry{R@\( \mathbb {R} \)}{1}
\indexentry{B@\( B \)}{1}
```

Note, however, that you as usual risk different entries for those `\index` commands that are inside arguments to macros.

Avoid it, if you can. Otherwise do

```
\newcommand{\asindex}[1]{\index{#1}}
```

or add `\string` in front of the control sequences in the argument to `\index` when the command is in the argument to another one.

Comment: Many thanks.  The preamble command works well.  How would one use the `\string` approach in this case?

Comment: @AndrewSwann You don't want `\string` in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
\emph{\index{R@\( \protect\mathbb R \)}%
```

Normally `\index` is read verbatim, but that does not work inside the argument of another command.