# How can I get the regular \mathbb and the kpfonts' \mathfrak using fourier?

Tags: kpfonts, fourier

I need to get the regular \mathbb style (the resulting one only using \amsfonts) and the kpfonts' \mathfrak style using the package fourier.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! In my opinion, you shouldn't: they don't fit well together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can; whether you should is a matter of opinion.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier}

\DeclareSymbolFont{AMSb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}
\makeatletter
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\math@bb}{AMSb}
% see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254979/
\AtBeginDocument{\protected\def\mathbb{\math@bb}} 
\makeatother
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathfrak}{U}{jkpmia}{m}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathfrak}{bold}{U}{jkpmia}{bx}{it}

\begin{document}

$A+\mathbb{A}+\mathfrak{A}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I use the `MnSymbol` package the command `\mathcal{P}` shows a nice _P_, but when I remove that package, `\mathcal{P}` shows a very ugly _P_ (in my opinion) thanks to `fourier`. How can I get the normal _P_ whitout `MnSymbol` using the `\mathcal{P}` command?

Comment: @DiegoD.R.Rivera You should be aware that `MnSymbol` changes all math symbols. There's no ”normal“ P, so it's quite unclear what you want to achieve. In any case, it is a brand new question.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't and I wouldn't, but technically you could.

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fourier}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\math@bb}{AMSb}
```

This is entirely untested since you didn't provide a minimal working example - or, indeed, any code at all - to work from. So you must be happy adapting it to your local requirements.